# JQGrid pager says "1 of Nan"?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pager

When I have no rows returned, our jqGrid pager says `Page 1 of NaN`.

The JSON returned is:

```
{"page":"1","records":"0","total":"1"}
```

Why is `NaN` listed?

---

**Update**: We only seem to have this issue when we use `loadonce:true`.

Here's the source code:

```
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'NoData.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Product', 'Type'],
    colModel :[
      {name:'product', index:'product', width:80},
      {name:'type', index:'type', width:55, align:'right'},
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:20,
    viewrecords: true ,
    caption: 'Positions',
    height: '460',
    loadonce:true,          
    hidegrid: false         
  });
```

---

**Update 2**: What seems to work is the JSON below - is this right?

```
{"page":0,"records":0,"total":0,"rows":[]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is wrong in the definition of your jqGrid. Look at [the simple example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NoData.htm) of jqGrid filled with your JSON data. You will see "No records to view" ar other text from `$.jgrid.defaults.emptyrecords` defined in grid.locale-XX.js (grid.locale-en.js for example).

If you will continue to have problem you should append your question with the code of the jqGrid having the described problem.

Comment: Took a closer look - see the updated post.  Only seem to have this issue when `loadonce` is true

Comment: I downloaded the example you mentioned - if I change loadonce to true then you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Marcus: I found the place where the error exist. In jqGrid 3.7.2 in  grid.base.js the lines 1098 and 1239 which has `if(locdata) {` should be replaced to `if(locdata && rn) {`. You can see the same example with the fixed code under http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NoData1.htm. The problem is that I find **MUCH MORE** problem in just published version of jqGrid 3.8. I have not a few time, but will try later write the corresponding suggestions how to fix the bugs in http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/.

Comment: @Marcus: I do took the time and posted http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/nan-as-total-number-of-pages-for-jsonxml-data-with-0-rows/ which describes the found problems.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  Is the workaround I posted in "Update 2" a valid workaround (if you don't want to modify the code)?  Or is it better to do the code change?

Comment: @Marcus: I agree, if you can change your code to produce data with `"rows":[]` it could be a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to reference the first page of a recordset with no records.

Comment: Surely jqGrid can handle a case where there is no data returned?  What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about change the option "pgtext"?

```
pgtext: "Page {0}"
```